# Uipicker background blur

Tags: ios, swift, uipickerview, uipicker

When a uipicker gets presented to a screen. The background has a Light grey blur effect in the background by default. How do I change the color of this haze?

Comment: There is no such thing as a "uipicker".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try using the below code.

```
pickerView.subviews.last?.backgroundColor = .red.withAlphaComponent(0.2)
```

UIPickerView consists of 2 subviews. One is the main container and the second one is the selection indicator. So we just simply change the background of the second i.e last subview.

Comment: This solution might easily break in the future if the structure of the `UIPickerView` changes.